# What is orthogonal projection of zero to triangle generated by three points (0,1) (5,0) and (2,4)

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

> What is orthogonal projection of zero to triangle generated by three points (0,1) (5,0) and (2,4)

Well, in my opinion, there is none. However, my teacher think that it has but he don't know how to find it.

Comment: I can't think of any way "orthogonal projection to a triangle" makes sense. What does your teacher think it means?

Comment: our task is to find orthogonal projection of zero to some convex hull in $\mathbb{R}^2$ but the set we find has three point and 0 doesn't in its. Is this any help to you?

Comment: Were the points supposed to be in 3-dimensions?

Comment: @rschwieb yes if we are in $\mathbb{R}^3$ it will be easier.

Comment: Are you sure that 'orthogonal projection' needed and not just *projection* to the *closest point*? Every closed convex set $C$ in $\Bbb R^n$ has the property that from any point $P$ outside of $C$, there is exactly one shortest path $P\leadsto Q$ with $Q\in C$... For a big domain of points, it will be indeed orthogonal to one of the sides..

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you mean the unique (but *not necessarily orthogonal*) projection of a point $P$ to a closed convex set $C$ as the endpoint $Q$ of the shortest segment $PQ$ with $Q\in C$, then

in your example, if you draw it, it should be clear that the shortest path from the origin to the given triangle is indeed its orthogonal projection to the side with endpoints $(0,1),\,(5,0)$. This has direction vector $(5,0)-(0,1)=(5,-1)$, and its normalvector is (any parallel to) $(1,5)$.

So, the projection of the origin is on both lines
$$\begin{align}
y&=5x\\
x+5y&=5\,.
\end{align}$$
And you still have to calculate its distane from the origin.

Comment: I had thought about it but it's still confused me about the "orthogonal projection of zero to the set". Is it the shortest path from zero or it has to be orthogonal to all point in that set?